# WordPress login page logo customization

Tags: images, login, paths, logo

For some reason the first code works. But the second does not.
And I can't figure out what is wrong with my syntax.

```
background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/flawless-v1-17-child-01/images/Logo-B-Classic.jpg") !important;

            background-image:url('.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/Logo-B-Classic.jpg) !important;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***get_stylesheet_directory_uri()*** is a PHP function, you must use it in a PHP file  instead of your CSS file.

In your functions.php you can paste this code and change depends on your needs:

```
function my_login_logo() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        body.login div#login h1 a {
            background-image: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Logo-B-Classic.jpg);
        }
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Simple Tutorial To Customize Your Wordpress Login Page : http://bloggingchimp.blogspot.com.tr/2015/03/how-to-customize-wordpress-login-page.html

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. While the link might answer the question, you should include the essential parts of the answer here and only provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [answer].