# How to display custom logo on WordPress login page

Tags: multisite, login, logo

I'd like to take a standard WordPress login page, change the WP logo to a custom image I create and that varies depending on site ID (WP Mulit-site).

I've found this approach: [WordPress login page logo customization](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177465/wordpress-login-page-logo-customization)

```
function my_login_logo() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        body.login div#login h1 a {
            background-image: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Logo-B-Classic.jpg);
        }
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

But I'm unsure how to best customize it to:

- Change the logo to a custom image based on site ID.
- Change the linking URL of the logo image to a url based on site ID.

Thanks!

Comment: What you'd want to do is create an option page where you can assign the custom logo on each of the multi site installs.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
function my_login_logo() {
    $site_id = get_current_blog_id();
?>
    <style type="text/css">
        body.login div#login h1 a {
            background-image: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Logo-B-Classic-<?php echo $site_id; ?>.jpg);
        }
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

Then, update the logo image file names to append the site ID accordingly to each different logo image file, for example `Logo-B-Classic-21.jpg` where '21' is the site ID.